# Rolled back on heroku, restored db, and now getting a ton of database errors

Tags: postgresql, heroku

We deployed some code tonight but had to rollback. The rollback affected the database so we restored our database to one we captured right before the deploy. Now we're getting all types of database errors, such as:

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownPrimaryKey: Unknown primary key for table billing_accounts in model BillingAccount.

PG::SyntaxError: ERROR: zero-length delimited identifier at or near """" LINE 1: ... "billing_accounts" ORDER BY "billing_accounts"."" ASC LIM.

PG::InternalError: ERROR: cache lookup failed for type 19005

PG::InFailedSqlTransaction: ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
```

I have no idea what to do about these errors, we're getting a ton of them. Help!!

Comment: all subsequent sql statements will fail after the first "commands ignored until end of transaction block". You should have a close look at your first failed statement. Could you post the first (10) lines ?